# Custom Cell Format ListView TornadoFx on delete item

Tags: tornadofx

I'm new to TornadoFx but am trying it out (also new to JavaFX by extension).
I have a listview defined as so:

```
 private var colorList = mutableListOf<Color>
//other things in init block
 colorpicker(mode = ColorPickerMode.MenuButton) {
                valueProperty().onChange {
                    if (it != null) {
                        colorList.add(it)
                    }
                }
            }(Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE).observable()               
 listview(colorList) {
    cellFormat {
       text = it.toString()
       style {
           baseColor = it
       }
      }
      contextmenu {
         item("Delete").action {
         if (selectedItem != null) {
            colorList.remove(selectedItem)                   
      }
    }
  }
}
//continue init block
```

Adding and taking away colors from the listview works just fine but the color inside the cell does not disapear if it is no longer occupied
[Example of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv8P7.png)

Comment: Please post a runnable code example :)

Answer (score 0):

The `cellFormat` function allows you to configure the list cell for each item in your list.

However, when there is no list item for a certain row, the callback is not run, so that you have no way of applying a style to an empty row using the `cellFormat` approach. One solution would be to implement your own `ListCell` and always clearing the `style` property of the cell, but I believe this might actually be fixed within the framework by always clearing the `style` property before a cell is reused. I just tried to make this change in the framework, and it fixes the issue with your code sample.

I will commit the change now, please try it out with `tornadofx-1.7.17-SNAPSHOT` :)